# How to align the top frame edges of source and formatted text with the same horizontal line?

Tags: showexpl

The following code will be referred multiple times in my questions later. Patching is needed to make the frames of both source code and formatted text inside the text width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=false,a5paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{showexpl,xcolor,caption}
\captionsetup
{
        margin=5mm,
        font={color=blue,rm,scriptsize},
        labelfont={color=magenta,bf},
        justification=justified,
        labelsep=quad
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\SX@codeInput}{xleftmargin=0pt,xrightmargin=0pt}{}
  {\typeout{***Successfully patched \protect\SX@codeInput***}}
  {\typeout{***ERROR! Failed to patch \protect\SX@codeInput***}}
\makeatother

\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},   
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\sffamily\bfseries,                                   
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    frame=single,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % the following must be defined to make hacking work.
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax, 
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    vsep=2\fboxsep,
    explpreset={}%must be called even if empty
}

\newcommand\dummy
{%
    Anger is a condition in which the tongue works faster than the mind \ldots
}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\dummy
\begin{LTXexample}[caption=\dummy]
\dummy
\[E\not=mc^2\]
\end{LTXexample}
\dummy
\end{document}
```

### Question

> The other 3 questions have been removed and the following one is left
>   to support the answer provided by Herbert. Use *edit history* button
>   to see the original.

In side-by-side mode (either `pos=l` or `pos=r`), how to align the top frames with the same horizontal line?

Herbert's answer plus `aboveskip=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax` will answer this question.

Comment: [Patching](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6517/how-to-control-the-left-margin-for-the-formatted-text-produced-by-ltxexample/6523#6523) only works when `frame=single` and `pos=b/t`. When `frame=single` and `pos=l`, the patch does not work because the source code's right edge goes beyond the text width as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it makes no sense to patch the command as you did. However, getting both on top aligned, insert in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter     
\renewcommand\SX@ResultArea[2]{%       
  \SX@justification\setlength\@tempdima{#1}%       
  \parbox[t]\@tempdima{\vspace{0pt}#2}}     
\renewcommand\SX@CodeArea[2]{%       
  \setlength\@tempdima{#1}%       
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\parbox[t]\@tempdima{\vspace{0pt}#2}}%       
  \@tempdima=\dp\@tempboxa\usebox\@tempboxa       
  \rlap{\raisebox{-\@tempdima}[0pt][0pt]{\SX@attachfile}}}     
\makeatother
```

Comment: +1 The patch is necessary when `pos=b` or `pos=t`.

Comment: `xleftmargin` and `xrightmargin` are set by `explpreset=...` and are parameters of `listings` and no normal length registers

Comment: I need to use `aboveskip=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax` and your code above to align the top frames.

Comment: Redefining `xleftimargin` and `xrightmargin` in `explpreset` will not help if `pos=t/b` and `frame=single` are used. Thus patching is really needed.